# Remote update each extjs grid row periodically

Tags: javascript, ajax, loops, extjs, extjs3

The goal of the task is to update each rows content from backend. Which means ajax request to PHP.

The table gets initially loaded with basevalues and  needs new, updated data loaded into each row periodically.

Making a ExtJs task that runs every minute, `store.each` will go over all records, get id for parameter and on ajax success, the record will be updated and commited.
However this approach comes with a flaw - if there is more then a few rows, sending 50 or 100 instant request will end up in timeouts for most.

Fetching all data at the same time and refreshing whole grid is not an option - calculating all the data for each of the rows will exceed the  request time limit (~30s), therefor the need to request each individually - but not at the same time.

IS there any good way to accomplish this in ext?

UPDATE:

I managed to use setTimeout as a delay for  ajax queries within the store.each loop. Every 5 iterations, the delay will be increased - so by the time the Ext task is done and all results looped over, they execute in batches of 5 every 5s - and start again once the task runs again.

Comment: You can use pagination. This way you limit the displayed (processed) results and it's safe to update all of them.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to send request to the server and get only changeset of items and the replace old items with changed ones.

If you don't want to reload whole store, the only variant is to send requests one by one, or pack them in packages and refresh them package by package.

Comment: requesting all the  records wont work in that case. Its fine if the grid has a few, but with 50-100 it will take too long - the math, queries etc required takes a few seconds. So in the end it could take minutes to return the result - way above the 30s  limit for the request.

Comment: As was mentioned above, the better way is to receive only changed records from server. Is it easier for you to implement? Or even with unchanged rows you need to do the math?

I usually have a column in the DB called 'updated_at' and can get only records that were changed after particular datetime.